# linking boost in 64-bit program VS2015

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I am in the process of upgrading a big boost-intensive program to VS2015, and boost 1.61. The program is a 64-bit program - x64

Boost seems to look for the wrong libraries in 64-bit mode (Or more likely I did something stupid). I believe I have built the correct boost libraries for the VS2015 platform.

I tried from scratch making a tiny boost function in WIN32 mode, that requires static linking. This works fine......

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void test()
{
 std::string line;
 boost::regex pat("^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)");
  while (std::cin)
  {
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    boost::smatch matches;
    if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
        std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

But when I want to compile this in x64 boost complains. Yes I have set the #include and link path correctly for both platforms. The libraries are not there.

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib'

libboost_regex-vc140-mt-1_61.lib

Comment: the `-gd` part of the name means debugging, try to compile your program in release mode or compile the boost libraries in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you've built boost at 64 bit
2. Check if you've added boost library folder to che Visual studio project (Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Folder)
3. Check if you're building your solution at 64 bit
4. If you're not using auto linking, chech if you've added the library dependency in project (Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies)

Comment: I should have built for the x64 libboost_regex-vc140-mt-1_61.lib and libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib C:\boost\boost_1_61_0>b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 architecture=x86
 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=minimal stage --stagedir=stage/x64   . I now tried making a console application from scratch. This works!! in 64-bit mode. Here it looks for libboost_regex-vc140-mt-1_61.lib. But a Windows application looks for somthing that is not there
agedir=stage/x64

Comment: How do you make newline in answers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the correct set of libraries the compiler is asking for. You should consult the [library naming chart](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) to get the build arguments (i.e. properties) to use while building. In your case it's looking for libraries tagged as "lib--mt-gd-1_61.lib". Which reading the chart says you would need to build with:

```
link=static threading=multi runtime-debugging=on variant=debug
```